# Arduino Uno - relay with separate power

Tags: arduino-uno, power, relay

i want to operate a relay with an ARDUINO UNO, but i want to use a separate power supply for the relay. Ive seen relays with VCC and jVCC (dont know what that is), but mine only has this pins: GND, IN1, IN2, VCC.
how should i connect it to the Arduino and the external power supply?
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a relay board set up for separate power supply. Those that do will have an opto-isolator per relay.

Comment: jVCC (where avail) is used to drive the magnetic relay coils, VCC is used to drive the logic/LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

This relay is designed to operate on 5V.

Most commonly this will come from the Uno's `5v` pin.

### If you want to externally power the relay itself then make sure to connect the `+5` to the `Vcc` on the relay board and the `-` lead to the `GND` on the relay board.

**Uno's `GND` must also be connected to the `GND` on the relay so the Digital outputs from the Uno will properly control the `IN1` and `IN2` inputs to the relay board.**

---

The Uno has multiple `GND` connections so it makes the most sense to connect the `-` to one of them then another to the relay.

---

Note that the Uno's 9V Vcc external power comes in through the barrel connector on the Uno itself. The Uno will pass power through its internal regulator to provide `5v` at the appropriate connection.

---

If you are switching external devices that run on 120V it would be on the screw-terminal side of the board only.

---

> To prevent accidental activation of the relays, note that this particular board is `ACTIVE-LOW` which means that as you initialize the output pins you should first set them `HIGH` so setting the pinMode will not default to `LOW` which would trigger the relay.

In the `setup()` section, using pins D5 and D6 as an example:

```
digitalWrite(5,HIGH); pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(6,HIGH); pinmode(6,OUTPUT);
```

Comment: The question is "but i want to use a separate power supply for the relay".

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino and the external PSU should have the GND or - connected with each other.

Then connect the external PSU + or Vcc to the relay boards Vcc.

Comment: Regarding jVCC see https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/RelayIsolation .

It is used when you have optocouplers isolating the power supplying the relay coil from the Arduino's power (VCC).

Answer (score 1):

External psu to gnd and vcc, in1 and in2 to arduino pins which control each relay (on is LOW) and most importantly gnd also to arduino gnd.